# PHP 5.4 in x11, but 5.3 in terminal

Tags: php

I tried to install php 5.4 yesterday but it doenst quite work. If i do `php -v` in Terminal i get 5.3, but if I do `php -v` in X11 it says that I have 5.4 and i can even start local server and it works just fine. Why doesnt it work in Terminal?
Someone said something about change things in my PATH, maybe thats correct, but how do I do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your $PATH variable.  
Both in X11 and OSx terminal type `echo $path`

Comment: hmmm, if I type that it only returns a black row. In both

Comment: My mistake, it should be $PATH but I see that you have found an answer already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have 2 versions of PHP installed but that the 5.4 is not the "default" PHP that is reachable from your PATH (an environment variable telling your system where to look for finding the program you're calling in your command line).

To find where the PHP 5.3 executable is, you could use the `which` ( http://ss64.com/osx/which.html ) command, on my computer it looks like this :

```
➤  which php
/usr/local/bin/php
```

On my system `/usr/local/bin/php` is just a link pointing to the PHP executable I want to use (I keep several versions of PHP installed on my system in `/usr/local/php/<version>/`)

You could check what the `which` command return and if the given result is a symbolic link like mine. If yes, changing the link to make it point to you 5.4 executable should do the trick.

Comment: it says '/usr/bin/php', and thats indeed where the old version is i think. 5.4 is in 'usr/local/php5. How do I change this? thank you ery much for your help!

Comment: @tobbe : if `/usr/bin/php` is a symbolic link ( if `ls -l /usr/bin/php` gives you a line starting with an L ) you can delete it and replace it with a new link pointing to your PHP 5.4 executable.

If not, you could create a link called php54 pointing to your PHP 5.4 executable or just uninstall the 5.3 version if you don't need it anymore

Comment: @tobbe I forgot : to create a symbolic link, use the `ln` command :

`ln -s <name of the link> <target of the link>`
e.g.
`ln -s /usr/bin/php54 /usr/local/php5/bin/php`